# Customize Distance Formular of K-means in Apache Spark Python

Tags: apache-spark, k-means, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

Now I'm using K-means for clustering and following [this tutorial](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-clustering.html) and  [API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.0.0/api/python/pyspark.mllib.clustering-module.html).

But I want to use custom formula for calculate distances. So how can I pass custom distance functions in k-means with PySpark?

Answer (score 6):

In general using a different distance measure doesn't make sense, because k-means (unlike [k-medoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-medoids)) algorithm is well defined only for Euclidean distances.

See [Why does k-means clustering algorithm use only Euclidean distance metric?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/81481/30364) for an explanation.

Moreover MLlib algorithms are implemented in Scala, and PySpark provides only the wrappers required to execute Scala code. Therefore providing a custom metric as a Python function, wouldn't be technically possible without significant changes in the API.

Please note that since **Spark 2.4** there are two built-in measures that can be used with [`pyspark.ml.clustering.KMeans`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html?highlight=setdistancemeasure#pyspark.ml.clustering.KMeans.setDistanceMeasure) and [`pyspark.ml.clustering.BisectingKMeans`](http://pyspark.ml.clustering.BisectingKMeans). (see [`DistanceMeasure Param`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/9b1f6c8bab5401258c653d4e2efb50e97c6d282f/python/pyspark/ml/param/shared.py#L705-L726)).

- euclidean for Euclidean distance.
- cosine for cosine distance.

*Use at your own risk.*

Comment: thanks @zero323: in your opinion why the library give us the ability to use cosine distance even though Kmeans is not well defined with cosine?